# Selenium - running javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

i've got dumb question - how to run scripts located on tested site? I can run alert, but i dont have access to scripts written by my. I've tried runscript, geteval - without any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Selenium is written in JavaScript the window object moves to within the Selenium object.

What you need to do is

`selenium.get_eval("this.browserbot.getUserWindow().youScriptOnThePage")`