# javascript in selenium RC

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-rc

I want to get webpage headers using selenium and I am thinking to use javascript as it already have XmlHttpRequest library which can help me, the problem is I don't know how to use selenium.getEval in doing that, or if someone can advise me other method will me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have information about how to run JavaScript code here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_How_do_I_execute_Javascript_directly?

Also you can check this: [Selenium - running javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398775/selenium-running-javascript)